# How can load a value in HTML after a JSP?

Tags: html, jsp, glassfish

I'm practicing HTML with JSP, i've been doing some exercises to steep up, but i don't have a idea how to load a value after returning from a JSP.

i have only 2 pages of code, the HTML and JSP

HTML:

```
        //var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
        function siexiste (){
            var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
            //alert(nombre);
            if (nombre === "") {
                document.getElementById("name").style.visibility  = "visible";
                document.getElementById("nombre").style.visibility  = "visible";
            }
            else{
                document.getElementById("name").style.visibility  = "hidden";
                document.getElementById("nombre").style.visibility  = "hidden";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload='siexiste()'>
    <form action="arttack.jsp">
        <label id="name" for="nombre"> Tu nombre </label>
        <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value=""/>
        <br> <br> <label> Color fondo </label> <br>
        <input id="fondo" type="text" name="fondo" value="" />
        <br> <label> Color fuente </label> <br>
        <input id="fuente" type="text" name="fuente" value=""/> <br> <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Presiona" />
    </form>
</body>
```

and the JSP:

```
<body style="background-color:<%=fondo%>;">        
    <h1 style="color:<%=fuente%>"><%=n%> </h1>
</body>
```

all works, but i want to come back to the HTML after JSP, and I need the value of "nombre" to be saved so that the label "name" and its input text don't appear.
I am using glassfish by the way.
If you could help me with this, I would really appreciate it. :)

Comment: Use Stack Snippets to include runnable HTML, JavaScript, or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can load everything in the same JSP.
So if you don't have a value loaded, the form is gonna show.
And if you have submitted that form, it's gonna hide and the values shown.

Something like this:

```
 <%

    String nombre = "";
    String fondo = "";
    String fuente = "";

    if(request.getParameter("nombre")!=null){
        nombre = request.getParameter("nombre");
    }
    if(request.getParameter("fondo")!=null){
        fondo = request.getParameter("fondo");
    }
    if(request.getParameter("fuente")!=null){
        fuente = request.getParameter("fuente");
    }

    if(nombre.equals("")){
%>

    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <label id="name" for="nombre"> Tu nombre </label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value=""/>
            <br> <br> <label> Color fondo </label> <br>
            <input id="fondo" type="text" name="fondo" value="" />
            <br> <label> Color fuente </label> <br>
            <input id="fuente" type="text" name="fuente" value=""/> <br> <br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Presiona" />
        </form>
    </body>
<%
    }else{
%>

    <body style="background-color:<%=fondo%>;">        
        <h1 style="color:<%=fuente%>"><%=nombre%> </h1>
    </body>
<%
    }
%>
```

Comment: The get back to the form, you can add a boutton where the values are shown or just delete the parameters from the url.